# Sed command runs with hardcoded value in regex but fails with variable in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

My file data Pattern is below and i need output as 6 or 3 or 8 or 4 based on the variable value which is eth0 and eth1

```
eth0RX:6:eth0TX:3|eth1RX:8:eth1TX:4|
```

Below code works well

```
sed 's/.*eth0RX:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' $EMSTATE/packetdrop.txt
```

But fails when I use dynamic variable like below

```
rxfile=sed 's/.*$iRX:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' $EMSTATE/packetdrop.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable expansion doesn't happen in single quoting. Use double quote instead. And if you want to set result to a variable, you need to run `sed` within command substitution syntax `$(...)` and better to quote this as well `"$(...)"`. Plus as `$iRX` can be a valid variable name better do `${i}`.

```
rxfile="$(sed "s/.*${i}RX:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g" "$EMSTATE/packetdrop.txt" )"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Inside single quotes, everything is what it is. 
   `$i` is a dollar sign followed by an `i`. 
   If you want to use a variable,
   you have to put the string into double quotes, somewhat like this:

   ```
   "s/.*$iRX:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g"
   ```
2. But that won’t work, because it will look for a variable called `iRX`. 
   The simplest way to fix that is to put the variable name in braces, like this:

   ```
   "s/.*${i}RX:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g"
   ```
3. You should put `$EMSTATE` into double quotes, too. 
   You can use `"$EMSTATE"/packetdrop.txt` or `"$EMSTATE/packetdrop.txt"`,
   whichever you prefer.

Comment: Yes, there is a significant overlap.   (My answer is not the same as yours, or a subset, as you didn’t *mention* my point #3.)   But, more importantly, I started typing my answer before you posted yours.  And I believe that my explanation is somewhat clearer than yours.